# Display an UIAlert when a UIImageView is touch

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, touch, uialertview

I have an ImageView and I want that when user press the image view to display a message as an alert. What method should I use? Can you provide me an example ?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: use UITapGestureRecognizer for that

Comment: in .h UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a UITapGestureRecognizer:

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
[tapRecognizer release];
```

And then your callback...

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecognizer
{
  //show your alert...
}
```

Comment: I get a warning at this line : tapRecognizer.delegate = self;

Answer (score 1):

Use Touch Events method to do ur task

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    CGPoint location= [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(urImageView.frame, location)) {
        //AlertView COde
    }
}
```

Comment: how to set a touch event for a imageview?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't intent to subclass `UIImageView` to override touch event methods -- or implement the touch methods in the ViewController and check the frame the touch lies in the imageview frame -- **you can (and that's probably easier) add an `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your `UIImageView`**.

[See here in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html) for more details

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* tapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapOnImage:)];
[yourImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGR];
[tagGR release];
```

Then implement the `-(void)tapOnImage:(UIGestureRecognizer*)tapGR` method as you wish

Answer (score 1):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapOne = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    singleTapOne.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1; singleTapOne.numberOfTapsRequired = 1; singleTapOne.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTapOne]; [singleTapOne release];


- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, 
Enable property

```
yourImgView.setUserInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
```

Then apply the below code on viewDidLoad;

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapOnImg = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(handleTapOnImgView:)];
tapOnImg.numberOfTapsRequired = 1; tapOnImg.delegate = self;
[yourImgView addGestureRecognizer:tapOnImg];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use touch delegate method and find your image view there,

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `UITapGestureRecognizer` if the class where you have your imageview overrides `UIResponder` you could just override `touchesBegan`:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
      UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
      if ([touch view] == YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW) {
          // User clicked on the image, display the dialog.
          UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Image Clicked"     message:@"You clicked an image." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
          [alert show];
          [alert release];
      }
}
```

You must be sure that `userInteractionEnabled` is `YES` for your image view.